# How can I show a div out of the box with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I want to display a tool tip for each element of a list, this list is big so it has its own div with a scroll. The problem is that, for the first element, the tool tip is out of the box and it is not visible, even it has position absolute and z-index.

If you take a look at this code, basically what I want is nothing but display the square in block 2 inside the block 1.

```
.square {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
   display: block;
   top: -20px;
   background-color: black; 
   height: 10px; 
   width: 10px;
}

.block {
   overflow-y: overlay;
   display: block;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: relative;
   border-style: solid;
}

<div class="block">Block 1</div>
<div class="block">
Block 2
<div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Note, I really need to have the position relative and the scroll, is it possible to achieve that? Which other options I have?

https://jsfiddle.net/daczfw64/

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Block 1</div>
  <div class="block">
    Block 2
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
}

.square {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    top: -20px;
    background-color: green; 
    height: 10px; 
    width: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/chocopuff/pen/PoYzbPw

Comment: The square needs to be inside block 2 (in code) but displayed in block 1

Comment: If you remove  overflow-y from my code, you can see what I meant, but I need the  overflow-y though

Comment: But I really need the scroll in the block 2 =( there I have a list of elements with a scroll